# copy to another book its not working

Tags: excel, vba, macos

Im working on an excell that is driving me crazy
evertyhting is working perfectly BUT it´s way to heavy and it takes too long to open and save 
So I decided to move some "sheet" to another book. But I cant get the code to work.

This is the code that works perfeclty all in one book

```
'Ariel
 If ActiveSheet.Range("C6").Value = "Ariel" Then
 filalibre = Sheets("ariel").Range("a1048576").End(xlUp).Row + 1
ActiveSheet.Range("A10").Select
fila = 10
Sheets("ariel").Cells(filalibre, 2) = ActiveSheet.Range("E4") 'factura
Sheets("ariel").Cells(filalibre, 1) = ActiveSheet.Range("E2") 'fecha
Sheets("ariel").Cells(filalibre, 3) = ActiveSheet.Range("C6") 'cliente
Sheets("ariel").Cells(filalibre, 4) = ActiveSheet.Range("f26") 'subtotal
Sheets("ariel").Cells(filalibre, 5) = ActiveSheet.Range("f27") 'saldo
Sheets("ariel").Cells(filalibre, 6) = ActiveSheet.Range("f28") 'total
End If
```

and I this is the code I try. I moved the sheet "ariel" to a new book. And its doing nothing

```
Dim wb As Workbook

If ActiveSheet.Range("C6").Value = "Ariel" Then
Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\MARI\clientes 2.xlsm")
filalibre = wb.Sheets("ariel").Range("a1048576").End(xlUp).Row + 1

ActiveSheet.Range("A10").Select
fila = 10
wb.Sheets("ariel").Cells(filalibre, 2) = ActiveSheet.Range("E4") 'factura
wb.Sheets("ariel").Cells(filalibre, 1) = ActiveSheet.Range("E2") 'fecha
wb.Sheets("ariel").Cells(filalibre, 3) = ActiveSheet.Range("C6") 'cliente
wb.Sheets("ariel").Cells(filalibre, 4) = ActiveSheet.Range("f26") 'subtotal
wb.Sheets("ariel").Cells(filalibre, 5) = ActiveSheet.Range("f27") 'saldo
wb.Sheets("ariel").Cells(filalibre, 6) = ActiveSheet.Range("f28") 'total
End If
```

can anyone please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you open a new Workbook, it becames the ActiveWorkbook by default. So all your statements using `ActiveSheet` are referenced to this new workbook opened. Those ranges probably are in blank, and you are getting nothing, because you are copying cells from same workbook.

Get used to play with objects like `ThisWorkbook` and `ActiveWorkbook` when you VBA code:

To make your code work, try this:

```
Dim wb As Workbook

If ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("C6").Value = "Ariel" Then
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\MARI\clientes 2.xlsm")
    filalibre = wb.Sheets("ariel").Range("a1048576").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    
    ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A10").Select
    fila = 10
    wb.Sheets("ariel").Cells(filalibre, 2) = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("E4") 'factura
    wb.Sheets("ariel").Cells(filalibre, 1) = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("E2") 'fecha
    wb.Sheets("ariel").Cells(filalibre, 3) = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("C6") 'cliente
    wb.Sheets("ariel").Cells(filalibre, 4) = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("f26") 'subtotal
    wb.Sheets("ariel").Cells(filalibre, 5) = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("f27") 'saldo
    wb.Sheets("ariel").Cells(filalibre, 6) = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("f28") 'total
End If
```

More information (in english, but there is a spanish version too. Looking your code, I guess you are spanish. In the link provided, just replace `en-us` and type `es-es`).

> [**ThisWorkbook**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-thisworkbook-property-excel)
>
> [**ActiveWorkbook**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-activeworkbook-property-excel)